# Extracting the first number in a field

Tags: filemaker

I have a text field, populated with values of different formats, some are just numbers e.g. "138", but some are of the form "139-1" or "139/2".

How can I extract the first number? Ideally I'd like to also extract the second number if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LeftWords` / `MiddleWords` / `RightWords` functions, before Filemaker 7 the hyphen was a delimiter for these functions, but it no longer is. However the `Substitute` function can be used to replace "-" and "/" with a space, so you can use `LeftWords`.

So `LeftWords(Substitute(139-1;["-";" "];{"/";" "]);1)` returns `139`

*Note: general-purpose text parsing functions `Left`(), `Right`(), `Length`(), `Middle`(), and `Position`().*

Comment: Unfortunately in Filemaker 7 and up, "-" is no longer a word separator http://fmforums.com/forum/topic/59000-leftwords-text-numberofwords/, however you can do this using the "Substitute" function. Thanks!